# brewing and storing small quantities in large receptacles

Tags: beer

i have a 22.5 litre fermenting bucket and a 22.5 litre pressure barrel but accidently purchased a 9 litre Belgian beer kit.Is it still ok to ferment and store this smaller quantity in these larger receptacles?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's absolutely fine to do, though the extra head-space might make for some minor difficulties in process. Things I can think of to watch out for:

- If you are taking regular gravities (which is always a good idea) it may be hard to draw them off a half-full fermenter. Siphon some out with a sanitized tube, in a pinch.
- If you look for a bubbling airlock as a sign of fermentation, you may not see nearly as much bubbling with so much extra head-space, even in a leak-free vessel. Checking the gravity or visually inspecting the krausen can help you assess the state of fermentation alternately.
- If you transfer into the pressure-barrel, you should do your absolute best to purge it with inert gas first (CO<sub>2</sub> or nitrogen). More head-space means more oxygen to displace in order to mitigate its ill effects on finished beer (think stale, wet-cardboard-y flavors and aromas). Even if you did a secondary fermentation in the barrel (priming with sugar to carbonate), without purging there would be way more O2 in such a large container than the yeast could effectively assimilate and neutralize.

So it's really fine to do, but it will probably amplify some issues you might not think/worry about with, say, a full 15-20L batch.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I have ordered a 10 litre fermentation bucket for this kit and will bottle rather than use the pressure barrel on this occasion

Comment: Sure. Was there any particular reason you decided to scale your equipment rather than your recipe?

Comment: Sorry, I missed your last reply, I just decided that it would be handy for me to have different sized fermentation vessels for future tinkering with recipes etc. I am considering a conical fermenter to add to my collection, do you have any experience/views on these? They seem a great idea to me!

Answer (score 1):

Fermenting should not be a problem, but I am concerned about the pressure barrel for storage.

The huge head space is a danger for oxidation, but also a problem for cabonation.
Unless you plan on using a CO2 cylinders to carbonate your beer, using priming sugar will be very hard considering the huge head space.

Why not buy a second kit and make it a 18L batch ?  Problem solved.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I have ordered a 10 litre fermentation bucket for this kit and will bottle rather than use the pressure barrel on this occasion

Comment: Good decision, you will avoid many potential problems.  Cheers.